# How to Hide the bottom Line in HightCharts (Splin Chart model)I am using in ios

Tags: swift, highcharts

** How to Hide the bottom Line in HightCharts here i am using spline charts model .Any one plese suggest **
[image]

please check above image and hide the circle inside dash in highcharts in latest swift code.

Comment: please add link which you use framework and your implementation on code

Comment: i got it answer .Any way i am using framework link https://www.highcharts.com/demo/ios @sergio_veliz thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need change value for:

```
spline.showInLegend = false
```

Comment: Or set [legend.enabled](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.enabled) to `false`